# Zend Retrieve Url parameter

Tags: zend-framework, parameters, url-routing

This is my first approach to Zend.Having this index action:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
 public function indexAction()
 {
    $this->view->variable="I'm testing my controller";
    if($this->_request->isGet())
    {
        $name=$this->_request->getQuery('mykey');
        $this->view->name=$name;
    }   
 }
}
```

and this view index.phtml:

```
echo $this->variable;
if (isset($this->name))
{echo $this->name;}
```

If I type this URL :

http://localhost/index/index/mykey/2

Shouldn't I see the "2" output in my index view??
I just see "I'm testing my controller";

P.s. need explaination more than a solution =)

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$this->_getParam ('mykey', 0);
```

instead.

Comment: $this->_request->getQuery('mykey'); is not a correct method to do what you want.

Comment: could you please point me to a reference or just shortly tell me why that wasnt correct?? thanks again

Comment: `getQuery` is for retrieving values from the query string, e.g. if your URL had been http://localhost/index/index/?mykey=2 then the code in your question would have worked. `getParam` also works for variables set by the router, so this is generally what you want to use.